# How do I read an HTML file in a JEditorPane?

Tags: java

Basically I have a file called FlowLayout.html and I want to read it into the JEditorPane. I have all the code up to that point but I don't know how to open the file in the pane.

```
  JEditorPane jtfInfo = new JEditorPane();
  jtfInfo.setEditable(false);
  p3.add(jtfInfo);

  public void getFlowLayout(){
    jftInfo.setContentType("text/html");
  //I dont know this step and setContentType gives me an error in netbeans Cannot find symbol
```

}

Comment: *"setContentType gives me an error in netbeans Cannot find symbol"* On the method, or `jftInfo`?  That method definitely exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call the `setPage()` method with URL pointing at the FlowLayout.html file:

```
public void getFlowLayout(){
    jftInfo.setPage(new URL("path to file"));
}
```

From the [Java Tutorial: How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html):

> "The setPage method opens the resource pointed to by the URL and figures out the format of the text (which is HTML in the example). If the text format is known, the editor pane initializes itself with the text found at the URL. A standard editor pane can understand plain text, HTML, and RTF. Note that the page might be loaded asynchronously, which keeps the GUI responsive but means that you should not count on the data being completely loaded after the call to setPage returns."